# Help with integral $\int^{a\sqrt{1-E/V}}_{-a\sqrt{1-E/V}}\sqrt{2mV(1-x^2/a^2)-E} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Hi I have tried u and trig substitution for this integral and just cant get it can someone offer a pointer or two? Thanks

$\int^{a\sqrt{1-E/V_0}}_{-a\sqrt{1-E/V_0}}\sqrt{2m[V_0(1-x^2/a^2)-E]} dx $

Comment: The units of this are suspicious. Is $m$ dimensionless? Why does it multiply $V$ but not $E$? Anyway, taking what's here as given, you could rewrite what's under the integral sign as $(2mV-E) - (2mV)(x^2/a^2)$, which could ultimately be put in the form $1 - u^2$. (Though you have to be careful about signs...what are the signs of $E$ and $V$?)

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry I omitted a pair of brackets, 2m should multiply the entire expression under the radical. $E<V$

Comment: Great, thanks for clarification. Integrals like this can easily flip from inverse trig functions to logarithms depending on the parameters.

Comment: @Surfcast23 If you are doing quantum mechanics (as it seems), you can also calculate this result by imposing a quantization condition as is done in the Quasi-classical (WKB) approximation.

Comment: @Jeff, I was actually calculating the transmission coefficient in the WKB approximation. Thanks!

Comment: @Surfcast23 Yes, that is sure what it seemed like :). Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can simplify the integral using substitutions.
$$I=\int^{a\sqrt{1-E/V_0}}_{-a\sqrt{1-E/V_0}}\sqrt{2m(V_0(1-x^2/a^2)-E)} \ \mathrm dx=\sqrt{2mV_0}\int^{a\sqrt{1-E/V_0}}_{-a\sqrt{1-E/V_0}}\sqrt{1-\frac{E}{V_0}-\frac{x^2}{a^2}} \ \mathrm dx$$
Let's set $\sqrt{1-E/V_0}=\alpha$, then changing the variable to $t=\frac{x}{a}$ one gets 
$$I=\sqrt{2mV_0} a\int^{\alpha}_{-\alpha}\sqrt{\alpha^2-t^2} \ \mathrm dt=2a\sqrt{2 m V_0} \int^{\alpha}_{0}\sqrt{\alpha^2-t^2} \ \mathrm dt$$ since it is a symmetric integral of an even function.

And in cases when $\alpha>0$ $$\int^{\alpha}_{0}\sqrt{\alpha^2-t^2} \ \mathrm dt=\frac{\pi\alpha^2}{4}.$$